# call js file from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, osclass

I have a js file called menu.js in the following path on my webhost

public_html/oc-content/themes/bender_black/js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nav-mobile").html($("#nav-main").html());
$("#nav-trigger span").click(function(){
    if ($("nav#nav-mobile ul").hasClass("expanded")) {
        $("nav#nav-mobile ul.expanded").removeClass("expanded").slideUp(250);
        $(this).removeClass("open");
    } else {
        $("nav#nav-mobile ul").addClass("expanded").slideDown(250);
        $(this).addClass("open");
    }
});
```

This code is a responsive menu, I want it to be reciprocated on all my pages. I therefore tried to call it from my header.php file which is located in

public_html/oc-content/themes/bender_black

Here is part of what I put in header.php

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/menu.js"></script>
</head>
```

The menu is supposed to release a drop-down on smaller screens however nothing happens. Am I calling the js properly?

How can I fix this?

Comment: **how can i fix this?** What exactly is broken?

Comment: please look again, I have edited the post

Comment: Without any errors, all I can tell you is : "Have you forget to include jQuery ?"

Answer (score 0):

Script tags placed in the browser are loaded by the browser. You therefore need to provide a DocumentRoot relative path to the js file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="oc-content/themes/bender_black/js/menu.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs absolute path like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mywebsite.com/oc-content/themes/bender_black/js/menu.js"></script>
```

But in Osclass case, you can register javascripts by internal PHP functions, which look like this:

Register the script:

```
osc_register_script('menu', osc_current_web_theme_url('js/menu.js'), 'jquery');
```

Enqueue:

```
osc_enqueue_script('menu');
```

If it uses jQuery, make sure you call the file after jQuery has been called.